# SAMEORIGIN vs CORS

Tags: nginx, nginx-config

I'm using nignx in order to serve an application that (can) make use of CORS settings. That means that in the dashboard of the application I can have some settings for restricting CORS to specific domains.

I also have this line in my nginx configuration :

```
add_header X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN;
```

But I also have these lines :

```
add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'Authorization,Content-Type,Accept,Origin,User-Agent,DNT,Cache-Control,X-Mx-ReqToken,Keep-Alive,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since';
add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
```

I understand that x-frame options has to do with being able to load the web application in an iframe or not.

My question is:

Should having CORS set for a certain domain name, enable loading code within the iframe on the domain names set as unrestricted in the CORS settings? Or in other words: should CORS settings be able to override the x-frame options line for specific domains?

Thanks,
Lex

Comment: You are allowing just your domain to use a iframe in the endpoint that this Nginx response. CORS just allow one other domain to uses the resources you provide in its endpoint.

Comment: So they are unrelated ... Do I understand that correctly?

Comment: yes, it is unrelated.